# CherryPy killed itself after I play HTML video element

Tags: cherrypy

I create a courses website. Sometimes, when I watch 2 to 3 videos, CherryPy is stopped.

This is my HTML video element:

```
<video controls controlsList="nodownload" src="${GV_base_url}/video/assets/lesson/${lessons_media_file}" type="video/webm" muted preload="metadata" playsinline>
```

This is curl information for my videos url:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: video/webm
Server: CherryPy/18.6.1
Date: Wed, 08 Sep 2021 11:41:38 GMT
Last-Modified: Sun, 05 Sep 2021 11:43:58 GMT
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Content-Length: 55867019
Set-Cookie: session_id=my_session_id; expires=Wed, 08 Sep 2021 12:41:38 GMT; Max-Age=3600; Path=/
```

This is the last log I get:

```
[08/Sep/2021:11:53:52] "GET /video/assets/lesson/8.webm HTTP/1.1" 206 79073937 "http://mywebsite.com/?chapter=12&lesson=8" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:91.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/91.0"
[08/Sep/2021:11:53:52] "GET /video/assets/lesson/8.webm HTTP/1.1" 206 234129 "http://mywebsite.com/?chapter=12&lesson=8" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:91.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/91.0"
[08/Sep/2021:11:53:53] "GET /video/assets/lesson/8.webm HTTP/1.1" 206 78582417 "http://mywebsite.com/?chapter=12&lesson=8" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:91.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/91.0"
[08/Sep/2021:11:53:54] "GET /video/assets/lesson/8.webm HTTP/1.1" 206 79041169 "http://mywebsite.com/?chapter=12&lesson=8" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:91.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/91.0"
[08/Sep/2021:11:54:40] "GET /video/assets/lesson/8.webm HTTP/1.1" 206 78466313 "http://mywebsite.com/?chapter=12&lesson=8" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:91.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/91.0"
Killed
root@myhost:/srv#
```

I can't see the cause of error from this log.

What may be causing this error?

Comment: Probably ran out of memory. Google the "OOM-killer".

Comment: @fumanchu Oh god, you are right. I checking killed process log and it kill the python. There is any way to avoid it?